# I can't send Transactions to safe-BSC endpoint. Internal Server Error

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I am using safe sdk to send transactions to safe multisig wallet using hardhat.
Everything was working well, but today I have got "Internal Server Error" during execution.
Is there any update in safe api ?

This is error message

```
Error: Internal Server Error
    at sendRequest (\node_modules\@gnosis.pm\safe-service-client\src\utils\httpRequests.ts:30:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async multisigBatch (\utils\multisig.ts:109:3)
```

This is my package.json

```
"@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk": "^3.1.1",
"@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk-types": "^1.6.1",
"@gnosis.pm/safe-ethers-lib": "^1.6.1",
"@gnosis.pm/safe-react-gateway-sdk": "^3.4.3",
"@gnosis.pm/safe-service-client": "^1.3.1",
```

Comment: I am having the same issue but using the python library through ape-safe. Out of nowhere, attempts to post transactions to a mainnet safe failed with the following internal server error: ```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head> <title>Server Error (500)</title>
</head>
<body> <h1>Server Error (500)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html> ```

Comment: This propably was a temporary error, let us know if it happens again